# Updating indexes on newly inserted data

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have an InnoDB table containing 1,5M records. On 3 columns in this table are applied indexes for faster search through this table.

I am about to add a new batch of 400k data to this table. The question is - how to optimise this table? Should I remove the current indexes and run the command for creating the indexes again (so the whole table would be indexed) or is there a command that would "extend the effect of indexes" also on the new data?

Thank you guys for your time, I am not much experienced in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexes will update automatically as you add rows to your table.

If you want the best performance, right before you insert your rows, issue these commands:

```
  SET unique_checks=0;
  SET foreign_key_checks=0;
  SET autocommit=0;
```

These commands speed things up because they cut down the work MySQL has to do for each insertion.  See here.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Then, as you do your inserts, use this command every 100 rows or so:

```
  COMMIT;
```

Then, when you're done with your insertion, issue these commands:

```
  SET autocommit=1;
  SET foreign_key_checks=1;
  SET unique_checks=1;
```

Finally, at the conclusion of your insertion work you might consider issuing the command

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE yourTableName
```

This will reorganize the table and indexes. Notice that the table will be unavailable for reading for a while during the reorganization operation.